# CSS Reset with PostCSS autoreset

Tags: reactjs, webpack, postcss, create-react-app

I'm trying out postCSS on a project using the create-react-app starter repo with postCSS and importing `.css` files for each component. That is, each component includes a `import 'styles/componentA.css';`, or several.

In order to create consistent styles across browsers I'd like to import a CSS reset. I've tried a few things:

1. Importing a `.css` file containing a standard CSS Reset based on Eric Meyer's reset.
2. Using the [autoreset](https://github.com/maximkoretskiy/postcss-autoreset) plugin for postCSS.

For the first option , in `dev` mode the CSS `imports` are added as `<style>` tags to the document. The CSS Reset appears last in the list of `<style>` tags, though it's imported in the top-level component. Ideally the CSS Reset would be imported first. Being last means it would overwrite any styles I apply to base elements (like `h1 {font-size: 40px;}`)

For the 2nd option (using autoreset), it doesn't appear there's a way to apply specific rules to specific elements. For example, I want to apply `list-style: none` only to `ul` and `ol` elements.

Is it possible to use the autoreset plugin to do a Eric Meyer-like CSS Reset in postCSS? Or am I going in a completely wrong direction and misunderstanding the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use react but I faced a similar issue when using components and resets alongside PostCSS (I'm building things as described here: http://ecss.io/chapter7.html). I didn't want a reset loaded for each component, just a global one as would be used traditionally.

Therefore, I went with a 'component' purely for 'globalCSS'. This is the first component that gets loaded and loads in the reset (and also global PostCSS variables and mixins) so subsequent components have access to them without redeclaring.

Is that an approach you could use/adapt?

Comment: As I dive deeper into it I've come around to the idea a CSS reset is unnecessary with components. Components should be able to live on their own, with no (or as little possible) effect from external components. With this approach the reset should be done on a component basis, and all styles for the component localized to the specific component.